# how to export a empty directory?

Tags: bazel

I need export all files include a empty directory in test_data directory,  use below filegroup not export that empty directory.

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])
filegroup(
    name = "exported_testdata",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run bazel build, empty directories are not automatically included. But if you are seeing issue in exporting it or wants to add it explicitly, you can add the `empty_file` inside your filegroup and set it as boolean `True`.

Bazel build will include the empty_directory with an empty file inside.